# Disable minimal download strategy using powershell

Tags: powershell, minimal-download-strategy

I am trying to disable the **minimal download strategy** but the feature is not available even though the redirection persists.

This site is a users Blog site. The Blog link from the MySite redirects here:
Blog/_layouts/15/**start.aspx#**/default.aspx

MDS is disabled at the top-level site. When I execute the following command:

```
Disable-SPFeature -identity "87294c72-f260-42f3-a41b-981a2ffce37a" -URL <weburl>/personal/<userid>/Blog
```

I get the following:

```
Disable-SPFeature : Feature '87294c72-f260-42f3-a41b-981a2ffce37a' is not activated at this scope.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Disable-SPFeature -identity "87294c72-f260-42f3-a41b-981a2ffce37a" -URL http://i ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tDisableFeature:SPCmdletDisableFeature) [Disable-SPFeature], Invali 
       dOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletDisableFeature
```

This is a list with all features int he blog:
    PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SPFeature -Web $blog

```
DisplayName                    Id                                       CompatibilityLevel   Scope                         
-----------                    --                                       ------------------   -----                         
WebPageLibrary                 00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18     15                   Web                           
BizAppsListTemplates           065c78be-5231-477e-a972-14177cc5b3c7     15                   Web                           
IssuesList                     00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100     15                   Web                           
SPSBlog                        d97ded76-7647-4b1e-b868-2af51872e1b3     15                   Web                           
PremiumWeb                     0806d127-06e6-447a-980e-2e90b03101b8     15                   Web                           
WorkflowHistoryList            00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-305cf7030140     15                   Web                           
ReportListTemplate             2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a     15                   Web                           
PromotedLinksList              192efa95-e50c-475e-87ab-361cede5dd7f     15                   Web                           
NoCodeWorkflowLibrary          00bfea71-f600-43f6-a895-40c0de7b0117     15                   Web                           
FollowingContent               a7a2793e-67cd-4dc1-9fd0-43f61581207a     15                   Web                           
SurveysList                    00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102     15                   Web                           
GridList                       00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120     15                   Web                           
GanttTasksList                 00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119     15                   Web                           
LinksList                      00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103     15                   Web                           
MobilityRedirect               f41cc668-37e5-4743-b4a8-74d1db3fd8a4     15                   Web                           
workflowProcessList            00bfea71-2d77-4a75-9fca-76516689e21a     15                   Web                           
TasksList                      00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107     15                   Web                           
TeamCollab                     00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5     15                   Web                           
BlogSiteTemplate               faf00902-6bab-4583-bd02-84db191801d8     15                   Web                           
AccSvcAddAccessApp             d2b9ec23-526b-42c5-87b6-852bd83e0364     15                   Web                           
BaseWeb                        99fe402e-89a0-45aa-9163-85342e865dc8     15                   Web                           
WorkflowTask                   57311b7a-9afd-4ff0-866e-9393ad6647b1     15                   Web                           
HierarchyTasksList             f9ce21f8-f437-4f7e-8bc6-946378c850f0     15                   Web                           
TaskListNewsFeed               ff13819a-a9ac-46fb-8163-9d53357ef98d     15                   Web                           
AnnouncementsList              00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104     15                   Web                           
PictureLibrary                 00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109     15                   Web                           
WorkflowServiceStore           2c63df2b-ceab-42c6-aeff-b3968162d4b1     15                   Web                           
ContactsList                   00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105     15                   Web                           
CustomList                     00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100     15                   Web                           
DocumentLibrary                00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101     15                   Web                           
DiscussionsList                00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108     15                   Web                           
DataSourceLibrary              00bfea71-f381-423d-b9d1-da7a54c50110     15                   Web                           
DataConnectionLibrary          00bfea71-dbd7-4f72-b8cb-da7ac0440130     15                   Web                           
ExternalList                   00bfea71-9549-43f8-b978-e47e54a10600     15                   Web                           
EventsList                     00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106     15                   Web                           
XmlFormLibrary                 00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115     15                   Web
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I had to add my account in the User Policy for the Web application:
CA -> Manage Web Application -> User Policy -> Add user

Second I tried the following commands and it worked:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <site>
$web.EnableMinimalDownload = $false
$web.Update()
```